# using canvas.drawBitmap() with canvas.translate()

Tags: android, canvas, android-image

My code here receives a value for `bmpX` and `bmpY` and uses them to draw a bitmap at that location on the screen. This works exactly as I want it to, but I would rather use the `canvas.translate()` function to handle the movement of the image, rather than just `canvas.drawBitmap()`, because I will be applying other draw elements to the canvas and I want them all to move the same amount and direction.

My question is: where can I move the `canvas.drawBitmap()` in the code so that it just draws onto the canvas at the start, but it is moved any time after that using `canvas.translate()` instead? Anywhere I place the code still freezes the image at that point where I draw it, regardless of how much I change the position of `canvas.translate()`. I'm imaging its possible to "stick" the image to the canvas, so to speak, and then move the canvas, which also moves the image with it.

```
public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(isRunning) {
            if(!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                continue;
            }

            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawRGB(255, 255, 255);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, bmpX-(bmp.getWidth()/2), 
                                     bmpY-(bmp.getHeight()/2), null);

            //canvas.translate(bmpX, bmpY);

            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

        }
}
```

I hope I explained my problem clearly enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here for clarity, afetr info I got offline. UI cannot be done on a thread like this, I needed to be using an android UI thread instead. runOnUIUpdatethread and async tasks